# Having issue with htmlspecialchars, where is the correct place to put it?

Tags: php, html, pdo

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO chatbox (username, message)
    VALUES (:username, :message)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
   $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $stmt->execute();
    ?>
```

Where would I put htmlspecialchars() in this situation, please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere here. Always try to put the "raw" (see below what I mean by "raw") data into your database. Only use htmlspecialchars when you want to show the data from your database.

**"raw" as in** sanitized and safe for the database, but not touched in a way that it is a certain format (e.g. HTML)

//edit:
So in order to use htmlspecialchars correctly, let's say you echo that message after receiving it from the database like that:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($message);
```

Comment: is correct, but remember to validate your string first for security.

Comment: This is my code for outputting data: $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM chatbox ORDER BY chat_id DESC LIMIT 4");
$result->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$username = $row['username'];
$message = $row['message'];
?>                                                              Where would I put the htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: Can you write that code in you initial question? In the meantime I edit my answer ;)